# C# DataGrid not showing Data in WinForm

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that I am trying to populate as follows:

```
List<pupil> listOfUsers = new List<pupil>(); // Create a new list 
listOfUsers = pupil.LoadPupilDetails(); // Populate the list with a list of all users 
dgvPupil.DataSource = listOfUsers;
```

The code works in another project of mine and I followed the same process but it won't appear. The list does return users from a text file. I have also break pointed and can confirm the dgvPupil.DataSource shows this data but it simply won't show on the rendered form.

Initailly, I had this code in the form load event, but I then tried applying it through a manual button click event to no avail.

I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Are data members inside `pupil` class are properties and `public`? Is `dgvPupil.AutoGenerateColumns` is set to true?

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply. Yes to both. So I have a method that reads data from a text file and returns a list of type pupil through encapsulated properties. I can see the data when break pointing through the three lines on the form, even down to data source on the DGV.

Comment: Try setting up each column in the designer and set DataPropertyName to the appropriate property from your pupil class than auto generating columns, set AutoGenerateColumns to false. Or just do one column to test if this works.

Comment: Do you see a DGV with no columns on the form, or do you see nothing?

Comment: Use dgvPupil.Refresh(); after dgvPupil.DataSource = listOfUsers;

Comment: @KarenPayne I will try that now.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock No, I just see an empty DataGrid. I tried a little test to loop the datagrid and output contents to a MessageBox and it isn't outputting so the DGV is definately not populating at all.

Comment: @MostafaSabeghi Thank you for your idea. It is still behaving the same way.

Comment: So, after following your instructions @KarenPayne, I am seeing 3 rows in the DataGrid which matches the number of records returned...but they too are blank. So I have a DGV with the correct number of rows and columns since I added columns manually but each cell is blank.

Comment: Can you post your pupil class?

Comment: You are going to have to add more code so we can test this. Currently the posted code technically “should” work. I suggest you create a [mre] that demonstrates the problem so we can test it. Otherwise, without the code that reproduces the problem, any solution would be pure speculation. I am just saying that if you can… _”confirm the dgvPupil.DataSource shows this data but it simply won't show on the rendered form.”_ … is indeed quite unusual. This sounds like you may be looking at the wrong grid, but again that is speculation on my part. Showing the `pupil` class would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay and thank you so much for trying to help.

I usually use encapsulation but for this program, I was aiming for simplicity and was using public properties. So I learned that my class required the properties to have getters and setters so that backing fields would be created at run time. This allowed the data to protrude through to the DGV!

Comment: Does this add anything to the existing answer?

Comment: I was merely pointing out how I solved it.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad it got solved, but this is really a comment and not a new answer.

Comment: Thanks - I'll know for again

Answer (score 0):

See if the simple code sample helps using mocked data. What is needed is to see code that you have as your current code does not really provide enough details.

**Note 1** I created the columns for the DataGridView in the designer, set header text and `DataPropertyName` to match up with each property in the `Pupil` class.

**Note 2** Learn to use a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

I would recommend creating a new form devoid of anything other than what is needed to diagnose the current issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PupilsProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly BindingSource _bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dgvPupil.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            _bindingSource.DataSource = Mocked.Pupils();
            dgvPupil.DataSource = _bindingSource;

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgvPupil.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"{column.Name}, {column.DataPropertyName}, {column.DefaultCellStyle.Format}");
            }
        }
    }

    class Pupil
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    }

    class Mocked
    {
        public static List<Pupil> Pupils() =>
            new List<Pupil>
            {
                new Pupil()
                {
                    FirstName = "Jim", 
                    LastName = "Adams", 
                    BirthDate = new DateTime(1990, 1, 2)
                },
                new Pupil()
                {
                    FirstName = "Mary", 
                    LastName = "Jones", 
                    BirthDate = new DateTime(1980, 11, 4)
                },
                new Pupil()
                {
                    FirstName = "Mile", 
                    LastName = "White", 
                    BirthDate = new DateTime(1970,10,9)
                }
            };
    }

}
```

Output for each DataGridView column

```
FirstNameColumn, FirstName, 
LastNameColumn, LastName, 
BirthDateColumn, BirthDate, d
```